# Read specific line from a text file into a Python variable?

Tags: python

I have a number of text files with a layout like below,

```
heading
subheading
info1
info2
info3
```

where the character count of each line will vary from file to file. For each file, I'd like to store line 2 as a Python variable.

I can load the whole file into a variable,

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

but I am unsure how to specify to read only line 2.

Comment: For generalized data handling, take a look at `pandas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read the entire file, just the lines *before* the one you  want. The simplest way to do this is with the `itertools` module.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = next(itertools.islice(myfile, 1, None))
```

The slice produces elements 1 though the end of the iterable `myfile` (with element 0 being the first line). `next` simply produces the next available item from that iterable, giving you line 2.

(I was unaware of the `linecache` module in the duplicates; that's a better solution for the immediate problem.)

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read one line at a time with the `readline` function:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    line1=myfile.readline()
    data=myfile.readline().replace('\n', '')
```

For some arbitrary line you can iterate through the file until you get to that line:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    dataline = 4 # any number less than or equal to the number of lines in the file
    for line in range(dataline - 1):
        myfile.readline()
    data=myfile.readline().replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: Mmm, this is a bit of a hard-coded solution; what if the OP then wanted the 50th line?

Comment: Good point. Updated for an arbitrary line.